# Java Thread which waits for new objects in collection

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrency

I have one thread which should execute some action when new object is added to collection. This collection is modified by several Callables. Thread which waits for new elements should be easy stopped after some time by boolean flag 'stopped'.

What are the possible ways for implementing that? I didn't find good examples of implementing that.

Comment: Are you looking for a (Blocking)Queue?

Comment: yes, it's possible solution
but I don't want to create infinite loop with while (running || !queue.isEmpty()). So for now, I want to review other options.

Comment: But you don't use `queue.isEmpty()` with a Blocking Queue.

Comment: @TestName I'm just curious what's wrong with an "infinite loop"? A BlockingQueue + infinite loop with .take() + thread interruption with the interrupt() method (instead of a custom volatile flag) is the canonical way to manage a case like yours. There are another specific things like Disruptor etc, but they meet very specific requirements like GC-free, low latency etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could wrap your collection in a custom one and register a listener. Example with `LinkedBlockingQueue`:

```
public class MyCollection<T> extends LinkedBlockingQueue<T> {
    
    private final MyListener<T> listener;

    public MyCollection(MyListener<T> listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void put(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        super.put(t);
        listener.onPut(t);
    }
    
}
```

```
public class MyListener<T> {
    
    private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    
    public void onPut(T t) {
            executorService.submit(() -> doSomething(t));
    }
    
    public void stop() {
        executorService.shutdown();
        // optional call to awaitTermination() here..
    }
    
}
```